# Executing SQL stored procedure in Visual Studio executable

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, stored-procedures, executable

I have a stored procedure in my database in a SQL database. I am working with SQL Server 2012. I would like to build an executable in Visual Studio 2013 in C# that runs this stored procedure. I have made a basic attempt however I run into an error just trying to make my `SqlConnection`. Below is my code. I have a `Try`/ `Catch` where the `Catch` sends my an email with the error encountered. It tells me that I receive the first error at line 22 which is my `using` statement.

```
try
        {
            //create a connection to the database
            string ConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AirMonRead"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AQB_RMS.p_Temp_AirVisionSiteLog", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                con.Close();
            }

        }
```

Edit:

The following is the error message that I receive -

```
encountered the error: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'metadata'. at
System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable 
parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable
synonyms, Boolean firstKey) at 
System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString,
Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) at 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString) at 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, 
DbConnectionOptions previous) at 
 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, 
DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions) at 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key) at 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value) at 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString, 
SqlCredential credential) at 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString) at 
LogWriter.Program.Main(String[] args) in 
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\DEQ\LogWriter\LogWriter\Program.cs:line 22
```

Comment: Can you show, screenshot of the error?

Comment: Error details please, and also, I reccomend you to avoid using this old SqlCommand, and try using **Entity Framework**, Code First or DataBase First (this allows you to map SPs)

Comment: @VictorHugoTerceros there's nothing wrong with a SqlCommand. Entity Framework adds a lot of complexity and for running a SP it adds zero benefit.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the full **text** of the error, including any inner exceptions.

Comment: I updated my question with the complete error message that I received

Comment: What's your connection string? I'm going to bet that's an Entity Framework connection string, given the `metadata` keyword. `SqlConnection` operates only on SQL Server connection strings ([those look like this](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/)). Are you using Entity Framework, or is the connection string just wrong?

Comment: I see I am using an EntityFramework connection string `<add name="AirMonRead" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.AQB_MON.csdl|res://*/Models.AQB_MON.ssdl|res://*/Models.AQB_MON.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;  
      data source=doaisd7880;initial catalog=AQB_MON;integrated security=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;User ID=MyUser;Password=MyPassword&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`

Comment: I get pass the error with the connectionstring `<add name="AirMonRead" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="data source=doaisd7880;initial catalog=AQB_MON;integrated security=False;User Id=AQBAirMonRead;Password=S04pBubbles;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"/>` however I am not sure if it actually makes a connection because when I run the code it does nothing.

Comment: Uhh... where do you execute the stored procedure? All I see is you specify the command type as Stored Procedure (`cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`) followed by closing the connection (`con.Close();`). What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I thought that ran the stored procedure

Comment: I added `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` after that line however now it is say it is not able to access the database and gives the wrong database. I don't reference this database anywhere

Comment: That may actually be the *result* of executing `AQB_RMS.p_Temp_AirVisionSiteLog` in `AQB_MON`. Try executing that on its own in Management Studio using the credentials you're using in the connection string, and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are trying to use 2 x databases, there are 3 things you need to check here.

1. Ensure the attribute

> catalog=***AQB_MON***

makes reference to the correct database. Judging by your question, probably AQB_MON or AQB_RMS

2. Unless you are referencing a schema other than dbo, it looks like your stored procedure is prefexed with "AQB_RMS.". Try removing this

   **Current**

   > SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("***AQB_RMS.*** p_Temp_AirVisionSiteLog", con);

   **Change To**

   > SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("p_Temp_AirVisionSiteLog", con);
3. To check if the connection is being opened and the stored procedure executed, you can use the [MS SQL Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler).